# ¿Cual es el uso correcto de mouseout() en Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Cuando se detecta el evento hover en alguno de los menus, las opciones deben deslizarse para abajo. Cuando el mouse salga de las opciones, estoy tratando de ocultar dichas opciones, pero por alguna razon no funciona. ¿Porque? No veo nada malo en la implementacion de mouseout() en mi codigo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(".level1-option").hover(function(){
     $(".sub-menu1-container").slideDown();
    });

    $(".sub-menu1-container").mouseout(function(){
     $(".sub-menu1-container").slideUp();
    });

});
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.header {
 background: white;
 height: 147px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px grey;
 position: relative;
}

.header-menu {
 color: grey; 
 position: absolute; 
 right: 100px; 
 bottom: 20px;
}

.level1-option {
 padding: 0 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 color: grey;
}

.level1-option:hover {
 color: #e6b800;
 cursor: all-scroll;
}

.sub-menu1-container {
 margin: 0 5%;
 background: white;
 height: 337px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #8f8a8a;
 position: relative;
 z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-menu">
      <ul style="list-style: none;">
        <li class="level1-option">option 1</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 2</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 3</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 4</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 5</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sub-menu1-container" hidden>

</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno revisando tu código el problema está en tu `css` y no en tu `js`, resulta que al `div.sub-menu1-container` le estás asignando un `z-index: -1`, gracias a ese `z-index` negativo tu `div` va a quedar por detrás de absolutamente todos los elementos del sitio incluyendo la etiqueta `body` es por tal motivo que el `mouseout` nunca se va a ejecutar por que realmente nunca estás saliendo de los límites del `div`, no se si me hago entender pero en resumen tu solución es quitar ese `z-index`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(".level1-option").hover(function(){
     $(".sub-menu1-container").slideDown();
    });

    $(".sub-menu1-container").mouseout(function(){
     $(".sub-menu1-container").slideUp();
    });

});
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.header {
 background: white;
 height: 147px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px grey;
 position: relative;
}

.header-menu {
 color: grey; 
 position: absolute; 
 right: 100px; 
 bottom: 20px;
}

.level1-option {
 padding: 0 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 color: grey;
}

.level1-option:hover {
 color: #e6b800;
 cursor: all-scroll;
}

.sub-menu1-container {
 margin: 0 5%;
 background: white;
 height: 337px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #8f8a8a;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-menu">
      <ul style="list-style: none;">
        <li class="level1-option">option 1</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 2</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 3</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 4</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 5</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sub-menu1-container" hidden>

</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Al `sub-menu1-container` le tienes asigando un `z-index` de -1 lo que hace imposible para el mouse interactuar con el div porque lo situas detras de todo elemento(incluso el body).

Cambia el valor de `z-index` a 0 o eliminalo y te funcionara perfecto:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(".level1-option").hover(function(){
     $(".sub-menu1-container").slideDown();
    });

    $(".sub-menu1-container").mouseout(function(){
     $(".sub-menu1-container").slideUp();
    });

});
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.header {
 background: white;
 height: 147px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px grey;
 position: relative;
}

.header-menu {
 color: grey; 
 position: absolute; 
 right: 100px; 
 bottom: 20px;
}

.level1-option {
 padding: 0 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 color: grey;
}

.level1-option:hover {
 color: #e6b800;
 cursor: all-scroll;
}

.sub-menu1-container {
 margin: 0 5%;
 background: blue;
 height: 337px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #8f8a8a;
 position: relative;
 z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-menu">
      <ul style="list-style: none;">
        <li class="level1-option">option 1</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 2</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 3</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 4</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 5</li>
        <li class="level1-option">option 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sub-menu1-container" hidden>

</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```